# Append html/other widget after a specific widget

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How do I insert html and/or an other widget, just after/below a specific widget in ckeditor?

The content of the widget is really just a h1 with some fancy extra methods. I got the element(CKEDITOR.dom.element) for the h1 tag which is the entire content of the widget, but the problem is that getParent() for this dom.element which corresponds to my h1 tag, always returns undefined. It's like elements in a widget don't have a parent outside the widget. So I can't use insertAfter(It just fails because there is no parent).

Comment: is getParent() a js function . or do you mean parentNode property ! 
Could you make you qt any clearer .

Comment: getParent is a method on the CKEDITOR.dom.element elemen (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element)